# Turning a nested object or array of objects into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, flatten

I am trying to get all object types into a single array, but can't formulate a good method for it.

For example, this array should be mapped into the following:

```
  const array = [
  {
    array1: [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      [{}],
    ],
    object1: {},
    object2: {
      object1: {},
      object2: {
        object1: {}
      },
    },
  }];
```

```
  const array = [
    {}, // array1_object1
    {}, // array1_object2
    {}, // array1_object2
    {}, // array1_array1_object1
    {}, // object1
    {}, // object2_object1
    {}, // object2_object2_object1
  ];
```

Tried my hand at one solution:

```
  const fields = section.blocks?.map((block) => {
    let propList = [];
    
    _each(block.fields, function(val) {
      if (typeof val === 'object') {
        propList.push(val);
      }
    })
    return propList;
  }).flat().flat();
```

which worked for one object, but I couldn't get a recursive one to work generally.

The other problem is that every object can differ with each other. I checked some solutions here but either they flatten the properties, or they have a uniform object schema.

Comment: What do you want to do with object properties that are not other objects?

Comment: What is `block.fields`?

Comment: Note that `typeof val == 'object'` will be true for arrays and `null`. You need to check for these first.

Comment: Is the final result just supposed to contain an array of empty objects? What's the point of that?

Comment: If not, you need to test whether an object contains any nested objects, and use that as the base test in the recursion.

Comment: What you want is a recursive depth-first solution where you append the last leaf to your results list. After having seen the end of each trail (i.e. a `number`) would you know to take the parent object.

Comment: @Unmitigated we might just discard them. For now, we just need to get all objects into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at object with no entries or with entries and their nested objects. Then build a flat array fo either enpty object or properties with objects or properties which are not objects.

```js
const
    separate = o => {
        const entries = Object.entries(o);
        
        return entries.length
            ? entries
                .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
                    if (v && typeof v === 'object') r.push(separate(v));
                    else (r[0][0] ??= {})[k] = v;
                    return r;
                }, [[]])
                .flat()
            : {};
    },
    array1 = [{ array1: [{}, {}, {}, [{}]], object1: {}, object2: { object1: {}, object2: { object1: {} } } }],
    array2 = [{ array1: [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, [{ x: 4 }]], object1: { x: 5 }, object2: { object1: { x: 6 }, object2: { object1: { x: 7 } } } }],
    result1 = array1.flatMap(separate),
    result2 = array2.flatMap(separate);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked really really great, I tried it with my dataset and this also includes the parent node if a non-object property has object siblings. So for {'array1':[{},{},{},[{}]],'object1':{},id:'kfmwu',description:'lorem ipsum',status:'alive'}, it will include an empty node for each non-object prop. It's my fault on that, I forgot to mention this earler.

But no worries, I'd just make changes to your great solution. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: please add some varois data sets to the question along with wanted results. or empty or not that's the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as intended? If it is an array or an object with only object values, we keep flattening the content, otherwise we stop:

```js
const array = [{
  array1: [{a1:1},
    {a2:2},
    {a3:3},
    [{a4:4}],
  ],
  object1: {a5:5},
  object2: {
    object1: {a6:6},
    object2: {
      object1: {a7:7}
    },
  },
}];

const flatten = (o) => {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o.map(v => flatten(v)).flat()
  }
  
  const values = Object.values(o)
  if (values.length === 0 || values.some(v => !(v instanceof Object))) {
    return o
  }
  return values.map(v => flatten(v)).flat()
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatten(array)))
```

The assumption is that arrays do not contain primitive values, otherwise you would have to check for that too.